# finding canvas boundary of a photo frame

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

[image: Photo frame]
Say we have a photo frame like the one above.
Starting from center, how would u find a rectangle with maximum area that can be used to draw (all pixels in the rectangle must be rgb(255,255,255)?

I need to find the x and y coordinate of point A and B shown in the picture.

[image: proposed algorithm]

One of my approach is to do this:
starting from the center, and expand the boundary like the graph above.
But I am not sure how you could write loop(s) like that.

Comment: Eventually I went with my approach, and determined that the area doesn't have to be the maximum one. Hence can be achieve in O(n) time.

Comment: I think I misunderstand the algorithm you depict here. Doesn't this give you the largest *square*?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure because I can't mathematically proof it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the flood fill algorithm: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill).
I suggest you to use sets to store the pixels to be altered in a set; that way the number of recursions to be done can be reduced.

Edit: I obviously didn't read the question well. Still, the flood fill could be used, if you used it it on a circle that is expanded.

1. Start with a single pixel, that is the center of your circle.
2. set the radius lager by 1 unit.
3. Find the pixels within your circle, get their colours using flood fill.
4. If they are the same color, goto 2. If not, you have the radius finding the rectangle is next.

This algorithm may give you a possible solution, but there may be more than one, depending on your frame - you should start developing using some simple frame where the correctness of the solution can be judged easily.

Edit: based on the comment, the problem is to find the largest area axis-parallel rectangle in a polygon - and luckily there is a paper on this: [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0925772195000410). Doesn't look as an easy task though.

Comment: In a complex frame like this, i think it is necessary to find all possible solutions and compare the area of all of them to find the best one.

Comment: I think I misunderstand the algorithm you depict here. Doesn't this give you the largest *circle*?

Comment: sure it gives a circle. But its center and diameter gives you a quite good approximation on the position of the intersection of the diagonals of the rectange and the lenghts of these. This is not an algorithm that gives the best solution per se, but probably a good approximation, depending on the shape of the frame etc.

Comment: I think there are too many possibilities where this is not a good approximation. For instance, you are assuming that the rectangle is a square, which is certainly not valid for most images.

Answer (score 0):

I would use brute force here. Choose a `y_bottom` and `y_top`, determine the corresponding `x_left` and `x_right` and loop both `y_bottom` and `y_top` over the width of the picture. In pseudocode:

```
for y_bottom in range (0, H):
    for y_top in range (y_bottom, H):
        # Assume that x = W/2 is part of the rectangle
        x_left = maximum X such that all pixels in box (x_left, y_top, W/2, y_bottom) are white
        x_right = minimum X such that all pixels in box (W/2, y_top, x_right, y_bottom) are white
        determine Area of box (x_left, y_top, x_right, y_bottom)
        store this box if Area is larger than max found so far
```

Comment: O(n^2) seems too much for this job. Since there would be so many pixels.

Comment: I agree that O(n^2) would be expensive, but I haven't seen a working alternative on this page yet, and doubt if it exists. Knowledge of the bottom part of the rectangle gives you no information whatsoever about the top part of the rectangle, so they are independent variables. If you want to speed it up, you could demand that the center of the photo is also the center of the rectangle. You can then rewrite it into an O(n) algorithm by obtaining y_top from y_bottom and the image dimensions.